# Daydreaming - Imagination not visually but aurally

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

In Germany there is a thing we call "Kopfkino". It consists of two words, Kopf = Head and Kino = cinema.

The English equivalent should be daydreaming for this. Most of the time you just explore your mind or picture a certain scene different. These two scenarios happen "visually".

But sometimes I'm just having the aurally part of this experience, in which I can start a beat playing in my head or even choose a song to hear. These scenarios only happen aurally and in a focused or normal state of mind.

Is there a word or phrase for not daydreaming but some sort of "phantom hearing"?

Comment: We generally say to hear music in one's  head. German doesn't have a word for it, so why even mention German ??

Comment: "Song stuck in my head" is a similar concept, but I don't think that is how I read your question.  I feel like I've heard author's say things "queue the violin music"  ...  like disc jokey's started up  vinyl track over the air.

Comment: @Lambie, i thought i would help answering my question, as the word by word translation is pretty clear and implies a visually perception

Comment: aural imagination versus visual imagination, and it is not a disease. I don't see why you chose a hallucinatory thing as your answer.

Comment: 'earworm' is in the space if it happens with a catchy tune.  But it is simply an artifact of heredity: some people are more visual and some more auditory.  I always here music when falling asleep, not visual dreams.  Check out 'hypnagogic hallucination'.

Comment: @eSurfsnake thanks, i will! I use the term earworm when i cant control what to hear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to judge for yourself whether this relates to yourself but a '**paracusia**' is an auditory hallucination.

I note that you 'start' the beat playing or 'choose' the song to hear so it is clearly not involuntary for yourself.

> A paracusia, or auditory hallucination,[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auditory_hallucination) is a form of hallucination that involves perceiving sounds without auditory stimulus.
>
> A common form of auditory hallucination involves hearing one or more talking voices. This may be associated with psychotic disorders, and holds special significance in diagnosing these conditions.[2](https://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/paracusia) However, **individuals without any psychiatric disease whatsoever may hear voices.[3]**

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auditory_hallucination)

> Paracusia : auditory hallucination:  A hallucination involving the perception of sounds arising from outside of the head, most commonly of voices, in absence of auditory stimuli, **which may occur in absence of psychosis or mental illness.**

[Medical Dictionary (Free Dictionary)](https://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/paracusia)

Comment: This is a medical condition; not what the OP was asking, was it?

Comment: @Lambie Well I was being deliberately careful. Both of my references make it clear that it occurs in persons who are _not_ the recipients of a medical diagnosis in regard to mental health.

Comment: There is a difference between having hallucinations about music and imagining the music in your mind. I would not call hearing stuff in your head a hallucination.

Answer (score 1):

In the world of music, this is called "musical ideation".  It means the ability/experience to hear music in your own head.  Mozart was quite good at it.

Comment: aka aural imagination